# how to open url on click push notification when app is not working in background

Tags: java, android, push-notification

I want to open Specific URL when i click on push notification when my App not working in the background(Killed)(it's going to the App not to mentioned Url). When my App is working(foreground) then notification working properly(it's open the Url)

Answer (score 0):

As we know that ,in PUSH NOTOFICATION either app is running on background or not but once we click on PUSH NOTOFICATION the app will opens by its home page.

So what we have to do, we have to sent source by push notofications and have to get that source in Launcher Activity either Splash Screen or Home Screen & according to this we have to do code.

**Below code   "AnotherActivity": "True"**

```
 { "data": {
    "image": "https://images.pexels.com/photos/87452/flowers-background-butterflies-beautiful-87452.jpeg?w=940&h=650&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb",
    "message": "Hello Abhishek, There is a offer for you "
    "body": "Grab Upto 60% + Extra 15% OFF on Flowers"
    "AnotherActivity": "True"
  },
  "to" : "/topics/all"
}
```

**Activity Code Here :**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("all");  
        if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {

            for (String key : getIntent().getExtras().keySet()) {
                String value = String.valueOf(getIntent().getExtras().getString(key));

                if (key.equals("AnotherActivity") && value.equals("True")) {
                    //Here you can hit Url
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("value", value);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }

            }
        }

        subscribeToPushService();

    }

    private void subscribeToPushService() {
        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("news");

        Log.d("AndroidBash", "Subscribed");
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Subscribed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

        // Log and toast
        Log.d("AndroidBash", token);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, token, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```